# If I have two push notification apps under one project, when I try to send a message using the FCM API key will both the apps receive the message?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

As the FCM API key is unique to a project and not an app, when we have 2 apps under a single project will both the apps receive push notification when a message is sent using the FCM API key?

Thanks

Comment: both app will get notification is they fall under same project

Comment: How can I send notification to only one of the apps? Also, what is the use of sender ID or app- ID ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All apps will get notification if they fall under same project(aka same server key).

If you want to send message to any specific app, you can not do that regular way.

But there is an option for sending topic message, which sends message to specific topics. You can use that to differentiate between apps and send message to specific apps

Comment: Okay. Can you tell me when we migrate a GCM app to FCM, does the API server key change?

Comment: @PrachiShikha as far as i know, it is not confirmed
**Note: If Google creates an additional server key for your project labeled, "(auto created by Google Service)," use this new key instead of your existing key.*
take help from here for migration
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm

Answer (score 0):

For sending a notification you need a server key which will get from the firebase project and a device token. If both are same for two projects, both app will get the notification.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Can you tell me what is the use of sender ID or app ID?

Comment: Without the server key, how ur suppose to identify u r firebase project?

Comment: I'm talking about the sender ID , not the server key.

Comment: Also, if there are two apps, how to you send a message to only one of the apps? (because both the apps have the same sender ID and server key)

Comment: you mean device id?

Comment: No, I don't mean devide ID, when you create a new FCM project you get a sender ID and a server API key. So I want to know 2 things:                                   1. What's the use of sender ID                                                                                            2. How do we send a message to only one of the apps that fall under the same project i.e., how do we differentiate between the apps while sending messages?